# TweetSharp - TwitterService send direct message

Tags: c#, tweetsharp

i am using the latest version of tweetsharp from their site (TweetSharp.Next - Version 2 preview 7)

whenever i try and call SendDirectMessage on the twitter service:

```
TwitterDirectMessage dm = TwitterService.SendDirectMessage("UserImSendingTo", "My twitter message");
```

i get an error:

```
Argument
Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: types
```

What is going on? I'm definitely authenticated as i can do everything else - is there a bug in TweetSharp?

Comment: Looks that way; (or you've not configured it correctl); try filing a bug on their site: http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Comment: Thanks - have submitted a bug ticket http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/75

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been solved by the latest release of tweet sharp